# Expose an EJB session bean as JAX-RS using Eclipse and Jboss EAP 6.2

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, web-services, jboss

I have EJB project and try to reused session bean as Rest WebService by adding annotation.

The following is what I am doing:

1) extends application to

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class QMWSApplication extends Application
{       
}
```

2) add annotation to the bean

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/ws")  
@Stateless  
@LocalBean  
public class TestWS {  
@GET  
@Path("/test")  
@Produces("text/plain")  
public String getTest()  
{
```

3) Then configure the EJB project as customized adding JAS-RS facet to the project.
Then on project explore, I can see there is URI under JAX-RS web service.
But after I add the the final EAR to JBoss server (EAP6.2), and test on the browser, I always get 404 error. I am sure URL is right since, on the project browser, I left click the rest full GET and the web service tester on eclipse has same URL and also get 404 ERROR. Anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have put up an example for this at https://github.com/alexcpn/rest_in_sessionbean
Tested with JBOSS AS 7.1.1. Note that a war file is needed in the ear, with a web.xml . This is using JBOSS inbuilt RESTEasy.